# Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk without polluting my Git repository?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, deployment, meteor, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure the deployment of a Meteor app to Elastic Beanstalk via the CLI, but I'm getting stuck with a good method. Essentially, I have a bunch of source code in a directory, then I run a `meteor build` command to package everything up such that ELB can actually run it. However, since EB integrates with Git, when deploying, it only deploys the code as it looked in your last commit on that branch. My question is how I can use git (or elastic beanstalk) such that I can have both a clean source code branch that I work out of, but also a commit-able bundle branch (that looks completely different from the source) that I actually deploy to EB? I can't do the `meteor build` process after deploying as that's not an installed package on EB... Does someone with more knowledge of Git/EB know of a possible way to achieve this?

Comment: I never did deployment on AWS EB but from your case i understand that you can make use of `git submodules` here. Like your main app code will go as submodule repo of your deployment repo.

Comment: In general, when deploying to PaaS you push your source code (unbuilt, without dependencies), and let the PaaS provider install dependencies (e.g. with Bower, or Python's `pip`, or PHP Composer, etc.) and build your app itself. [This might be helpful](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/VxMQzpVFpME).

Comment: @Chris - That seems to be the only tutorial on the internet for deploying a Meteor app to EB, but he only covers manually zipping and uploading the files via the AWS Console online...

Comment: @ajduke- I think this is what I'm looking for! I'll read up on submodules (hopefully my brain won't bleed too much) and report back.

Comment: @GrantDavidBachman, that's unfortunate. I have experience using EB with Python (which works much as I described earlier), but I've never used Meteor.

Comment: @Chris I mean I could *probably* continuously backpedal by 1. committing my source, 2. building/commiting, 3. deploying, 4. doing a reset HEAD^, but that seems really messy.